# Using SQLAlchemy outside of flask error

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I trying to create a system with models that can be used within the flask's app context and by external jobs. 
I have created a database.py with the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Integer, String, Float, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class Stock(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Stock'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ticker = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    time_stamp = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    open = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    high = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    low = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    close = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    volume = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    price = Column(Float, nullable=True)
```

I have also then created a flask_db.py file:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from database import metadata

db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=metadata)
```

This is then used in my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_db import db
import os

# create the flask app
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="dist/", static_folder="dist/", static_url_path="")

# config
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

# initialise db
db.init_app(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    """
    renders basic index page
    :return: template
    """
    return render_template("index.html")


# app entry point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I run a file called create_db.py:

```
from flask_db import db
db.create_all()
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

I am not really sure why no application is found.

Answer (score 1):

The db extension will only get initialized when `init_app` is called, and the app context will only get created when the app is run. But because you're importing from your flask_db module, neither of those things happens - the code in the app module never gets run by the Python interpreter.

What you probably need to do is something like this:

```py
from app import app, db

app_ctx = app.app_context()
ctx.push()
db.create_all()
ctx.pop()
```

I would think that should work. But I strongly suggest you look into using the [application factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/) to create your app, and using [click commands](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/cli/#custom-commands) (with the `with_appcontext` decorator) to add to Flask's cli interface, instead of using one-off scripts. Also, it's probably worth using [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for proper database migrations.

EDIT: in your app module, you probably also need to tell Flask-SQLAlchemy about your custom base model:

```py
db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=metadata, model_class=Base)
```

Comment: That works! Thanks :). I am looking into the factory pattern as my application is now becoming a bit of a mess!